# I do not understand a many_to_one <=> one_to_one model association

Tags: ruby, associations, one-to-one, many-to-one, sequel

how to say? I do not understand what the sequel documentation tries to tell me about associations in case of a two models linked over a foreign key in one model A being a primary key in the other in a may_to_one case.
I always thought: If it is many_to _one in one direction it has to be one_to_many in the other... but the sequel provides a confusing chapter meant to clarify the topic with in addition an example I cannot follow.

It says in 
["Differences Between many_to_one and one_to_one"](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/association_basics.rdoc)

> If you want  to setup a 1-1 relationship between two models, where the foreign > key in one table references the associated table directly, you have to use
>   many_to_one in one model, and one_to_one in the other model. How do
>   you know which to use in which model? The simplest way to remember is
>   that the model whose table has the foreign key uses many_to_one, and
>   the other model uses one_to_one"

And continues to provide this strange example:

```
# Database schema:
#  artists            albums
#   :id   <----\       :id
#   :name       \----- :artist_id 
#                      :name

class Artist
  one_to_one :album
end
class Album
  many_to_one :artist
end
```

In albums I may find several rows pointing to same artist... why shouldn't the artist point back to all his/her albums? 
The sequel docu is crazy hard to read in many cases but this chapter reads easy but makes no sense for me:(

Comment: Because you only ever need the relationship to be specified in one table, and with a many-to-one relationship, it makes sense to have a single field in each "child" record that points to the parent record id. If you are looking for all children of a parent, you query for all child records having a parent_id field equal to the parent's id.

Comment: I agree this example makes very little sense since it seems to be implying that an `Artist` can only have 1 `Album` (`one_to_one`) but that many `Album`s can belong to 1 `Artist` (`many_to_one`). I think this is just mean to show the difference between the associations since each is more explicitly documented above but they could have chosen a far better example

Comment: I sat there infront of a not running model ( at the end a plural s too much... as it is not always clear in sequel if a model or a table is meant) ... I opened docu at 4 am after s long night at the screen and found this „extra  coarification)... i still cannot imagine a single scenario where a many to one is doubled by a one to one in return in a logical way. Thats why i thought i missed a big concept while coming from sql to sequel models.

Comment: one_to_one is useful because it returns the object directly while in the many associations you have an array. It's also faster because it forces sequel to pick the first result instead of going throught he whole table looking for hits.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me.

```
require "logger"
require "sequel"

db = Sequel.connect "postgres://localhost/postgres", :logger => Logger.new(STDOUT)

db.drop_table :artists, :cascade => true if db.table_exists?(:artists)
db.create_table :artists do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key :album_id, :albums
end

db.drop_table :albums, :cascade => true if db.table_exists?(:albums)
db.create_table :albums do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key :artist_id, :artists
end

class Artist < Sequel::Model(db[:artists])
  one_to_one :album
end
class Album < Sequel::Model(db[:albums])
  one_to_one :artist
end

artist_1 = Artist.create
album_1  = Album.create

artist_1.update :album => album_1
album_1.reload
puts album_1.artist.nil?

artist_2 = Artist.create
album_2  = Album.create

album_2.update :artist => artist_2
artist_2.reload
puts artist_2.album.nil?
```

We can fix this example by replacing any of `one_to_one` into `many_to_one`.

```
class Album
  many_to_one :artist
end
```

In this case `artist.album_id` won't be used.

```
class Artist
  many_to_one :albums
end
```

In this case `album.artist_id` won't be used.

The problem is that method names `one_to_one` and `many_to_one` were selected by underlying `sequel` logic and they are not user friendly.

You can create user friendly aliases for these methods. I prefer just to use it with comments. For example:

```
db.create_table :artists do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key :album_id, :albums
end    
db.create_table :albums do
  primary_key :id
end

class Artist < Sequel::Model(db[:artists])
  many_to_one :album # I have album_id foreign key
end
class Album < Sequel::Model(db[:albums])
  one_to_one :artist # I don't have artist_id foreign key
end
```